# Система тестирования. Как правильней спроектировать БД?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, uml

Здравствуйте! Делаю довольно простую систему тестирования: N вопросов с каким-то числом вариантов ответов в каждом вопросе.
Идентификация по логину, далее формируется список вопросов, пользователь отмечает нужные, нажимает кнопочку отправить и данные улетают в БД. После чего они сверяются с ответами в БД и показываются на экран. Всё.

Четыре типа вопросов:

1) Выбирается один вариант

2) Можно выбрать 1 и более вариант ответа

3) Произвольный ответ в текстовое поле

4) Комбинированный (текстовое поле и чекбоксы), но с одним вариантом ответа

Так вот. Если бы тип вопроса был бы только 1ый (где один вариант ответа), то было бы как-то так:

|[image: Так]

Т.е текст ответа юзера, записанный в БД сравнивался бы с правильным ответом после чего выводилось на экран TRUE/FALSE.
А как сделать с типами вопросов? Спасибо.

Comment: а что значит *Выбирается один вариант*? это типа «машина может быть любого цвета при условии, что этот цвет — чёрный»?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Вопрос и 4 варианта ответа. Можно выбрать только один вариант. Ну это прототип теста знаний как бы.

Comment: понял. сейчас дополню ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

логично, чтобы в таблице с вопросами хранился и тип вопроса.

ответы типа «набор пунктов» можно хранить в виде отсортированного по возрастанию набора чисел (номеров пунктов), разделённых запятыми.

---

**итого**

таблицу вопросов можно дополнить столбцом с вариантом ответа (*int*).

таблицы *ответ* и *ответ юзера* можно дополнить двумя стобцами:

1. *int*, в котором будет храниться ответ для первого типа вопросов
2. *text*, в котором будет храниться набор чисел, разделённых запятыми, для второго типа вопросов

для сохранения произвольного текста (третий тип вопросов) столбец на представленной картинке уже имеется.

а для четвёртого типа уже всё есть: и столбец для хранения номера ответа (*int*), и столбец для произвольного текста.

Comment: как-то так?  [новая картинка](http://prntscr.com/7qm0cv)

Comment: да, примерно так. разве что столбцы `secondtype` и `thirdtype` в обоих таблицах, как мне кажется, несколько излишни: ведь ни вопрос ни ответ не могут быть двух типов **одновременно**, а т.к. тип данных один и тот же, я думаю, можно использовать один столбец в данном случае. впрочем, если вы планируете делать набор типов вопросов-ответов не фиксированным, а расширяемым, то избыточность оправданна, хотя и сама организация данных в таком случае должна быть несколько иной.

Comment: а вот тут ещё вопрос. Есть таблица тестов. [http://prntscr.com/7ug8jk](картинка) Там одна таблица теста - один тест. Чтобы создать новый тест - нужно создать новую таблицу. Проще говоря - не правильно.

Comment: здесь принято задавать вопросы с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» (в правом верхнем углу страницы). а дискуссии в комментариях сводить к минимуму, и, в случае необходимости, пользоваться [чатом](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) (ссылка внизу страницы).

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так. С такой структурой можно комбинировать типы контролов как хочешь. Не идеально конечно, но работать будет.

```
    questions
    ---------
    id
    question

    answers
    -------
    id
    answer
    is_right
    type: checbox|radio|text
    question_id

    user_answers
    ------------
    id
    user_id
    question_id
    answer_id
    value
```