# Система тестирования 2. Как правильней спроектировать БД?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

В продолжение [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/434327/178576).

Имеется примерно такая структура БД:

Таблица Тест хранит в себе номер вопроса и три ответа к нему.

Таблица Answer - правильный ответ к вопросу.

Интересует, собственно, таблица Тест. Она не расширяема, как видите. Чтобы создать новый тест - нужно создавать новую таблицу, чтобы добавить ещё несколько вариантов ответа - нужно создавать новые столбцы.

Как сделать правильно? Спасибо.

[image: Картинка]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот хорошее расширяемое решение:

```
[question]
id
text
qtype

[answer]
id
text
isright
question_id
order

[user_answer]
id
user_id
question_id
answer_id
text
```

Пример данных:

```
[question] 
id text                   qtype
1  "Сколько лун на небе?" 1    
2  "Столица Франции?"     1

[answer]
id text      isright question_id order
1 "Одна"     1       1           1
2 "Две"      0       1           2
3 "Три"      0       1           3
4 "Париж"    1       2           1
5 "Лондон"   0       2           2    
6 "Нью-Йорк" 0       2           3

[user_answer]
id user_id question_id answer_id text
1  1       1           1         ""
2  1       2           2         ""
```

Comment: Согласен. Хотел топикстартеру посоветовать ссылаться на id правильного ответа из первой таблицы, но так даже лучше

Comment: @pavelip в user_answer если юзер вводит свой текст, а не выбирает radiobutton получается text="ответ_юзера", то answer_id - пустой?

Comment: Да, можно так. Туда же можно записать, если пользователь выбирает несколько ответов. Если этот вариант не подходит, то можно сделать еще одно табличку для нескольких ответов.

Answer (score 1):

`QUESTION: idQ | TypeQ | TextQ`

`TEST: id | idQ | Answer` - привязываете сколько угодно ответов к вопросу

`ANSWER: id | idQ | TrueAnswer` - правильные ответы привязываете к id вопроса

Comment: Зачем нужна таблица Test???